# Is there any way to have a fieldset width only be as wide as the controls in them?

Tags: html, css, fieldset

It seems that fieldset defaults to 100% width of its container. Is there any way that you can have the field set just be as big as the widest control inside the fieldset?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`, though you need to wrap it inside a DIV to keep it from actually displaying inline.  Tested in Safari.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fieldset-auto-width {
         display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<div>
  <fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width">
      <legend>Blah</legend>
      ...
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a better/ simpler idea than my answer if it works across all the browsers you care about.

Comment: FYI: `display: inline-block;` doesn't work in iE6 and IE7. Happy you if you don't have to care about them. :)

Comment: Works great in IE8 and Firefox 10!

Comment: What is the voodoo with the div. It appears necessary, but why?

Comment: @superluminary  Normally a `fieldset` will display as a block element the full width of the page. Making it inline, rather than block, allows the width to collapse to the content, but removes it's role as preserving the vertical flow of the page.  Wrapping it in the `div`, another block element, compensates for that and preserves the vertical flow.

Comment: The solution didn't work for me. I had to set `fieldset{
    min-width: auto;
}` as fieldset uses min-width as -webkit-min-content, as mentioned in the following post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660423/fieldset-width-100-of-parent.

Answer (score 17):

`fieldset {display:inline}` or `fieldset {display:inline-block}`

If you want to separate two fieldsets vertically, use a single `<br/>` between them. This is semantically correct and no harder than it has to be.

Comment: for IE 11, display:inline worked, but not display:inline-block

Answer (score 8):

You could float it, then it will only be as wide as its contents, but you'll have to make sure you clear those floats.

Answer (score 1):

This also works.

```
fieldset {
  width:0px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have multiple elements within the fieldset that should appear on the same line.

Comment: Sure it does, if you use a block element to wrap them or a combination of nowrap and explicit breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither `display:inline-block` nor `width:0px` works in Internet Explorer up to version 8. I have not tried Internet Explorer 9. Much as I would like to ignore Internet Explorer, I can't.

The only option that works on Firefox and Internet Explorer 8 is `float:left`. The only slight drawback is that you have to remember to use `clear:both` on the element that follows the form.  Of course, it will be very obvious if you forget ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<fieldset style="max-width: max-content;" >
   <legend>Blah</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I think you should apply style="max-width: max-content;" on the fieldset tag

Comment: Yes, it works nicely, after applying @Benoît 's suggestion (which I edited into the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use CSS to constrain the width of the fieldset, which would also constrain the controls inside.

I find that I often have to constrain the width of `select` controls, or else really long option text will make it totally unmanageable.

Comment: but i want to have it dynamic so the fieldset will "autosize" and not be a predetermined width

Answer (score 0):

```
 fieldset {

    min-width: 0;

    max-width: 100%;

    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Please add some explainations

Comment: Not even Tim Berners-Lee could tell you why this work but shit just works lol thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`width: fit-content;` works.

- [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)
- [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content)

Answer (score -1):

i fixed my issue by override legend style  as Below

```
.ui-fieldset-legend
{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Going further of Mihai solution, cross-browser left aligned:

```
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <FORM>
        <FIELDSET>
          ...
        </FIELDSET>
      </FORM>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Cross-browser right aligned:

```
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD WIDTH=100%></TD>
    <TD>
      <FORM>
        <FIELDSET>
          ...
        </FIELDSET>
      </FORM>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: While this might work, tables aren't usually considered good practice for layouts...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: imagine doing this for 5 fieldsets? 10? 15??! don't do it!

Comment: For any new devs coming here. Don't do this. You'll use 10 times more code than you need.

Answer (score -2):

```
            <table style="position: relative; top: -0px; left: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>   
                            <fieldset style="width:0px">
                                <legend>A legend</legend>
                                <br/>
                                <table cellspacing="0" align="left">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align='left' style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also put the fieldset inside a table, like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <fieldset>
           .......
           </fieldset>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```