# <fieldset>'s width in html

Tags: html, fieldset

I have an issue with the width of a fieldset. It's not auto adjusting to it's content. It sets the width to the width of the screen. Is there a way to set it to auto adjust to the width of the content of the fieldset?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302495/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-fieldset-width-only-be-as-wide-as-the-controls-in-them

Comment: The solution didn't work for me. I had to set `fieldset{
    min-width: auto;
}` as fieldset uses min-width as -webkit-min-content, as mentioned in the following post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660423/fieldset-width-100-of-parent.

Answer (score 10):

A fieldset is as large as the parent container, just like any *block-level* element, if you do not give it a fixed width.
So you have to make it `display: inline-block`.

Comment: It was the width of the page for me. It couldn't have cared less about the parent.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
    <fieldset style="width:0px">

    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is an example : http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html

Answer (score -2):

Sett the width to 0
Hml:

```
<fieldset class="field">
</fieldset>
```

Css:

```
.field {
    width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<fieldset style="width:270px">
```

Comment: Answered mine! Thank you.