# fieldset width 100% of parent

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I need to have a scrollable div inside a fieldset. My problem is that a fieldset expands to it's contents width instead of staying withing its parent.

```
<div class="section">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="list">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UziTech/tg5uk25L/

The two boxes should both have scrollbars on the bottom but the top one is in a fieldset so it won't control the overflow.

How do I get the fieldset to only be as wide as it's parent?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Browsers have custom css in their default stylesheet for `fieldset` elements.

On Chrome it has `min-width: -webkit-min-content;`

You could just set this rule :

```
.section fieldset{
    min-width: 0;
}
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tg5uk25L/4/

Inspect the elements with Firebug, Chrome Dev Tools, aso to see the difference between the `div` and the `fieldset` elements in your stylesheet!

Comment: thank you. I thought it could be something like that but I wasn't looking at the right property.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help Firefox...

Comment: I thought `width` always overides `min-width` and `max-width`.  Good to know.

Comment: Fieldsets can be dangerous.

Comment: how do we fix the dumb firefox?

Comment: @Adaptabi inspect the element, you'll see the browser's default stylesheet's styles applied to the element and it'll give you the hints you need.

Comment: Nice hack to resolve this buggy problem ;)

Comment: This is lifesaver material.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `overflow: scroll` on the parent `.section`. That will contain the overflow and add scrollbars.

```
.section {
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px double;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll; <----
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tg5uk25L/2/)

Comment: I want the fieldset to be 100% width of it's parent. I don't want it to scroll. I want the div inside the fieldset to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

from your jsfiddle, perhaps you forget to add a fieldset to the second section

this is a quick fix

```
.section {
    width: 100%;
    border: 10px double;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

td {
    padding: 0 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oussamaelgoumri/meqvbjf1/

Comment: I purposely did that to show that it works with a div but not with a fieldset