# How to make Fieldset as wide as its parent (match parent width)

Tags: html, css, fieldset

Let's take a look at this code:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li><a>ردیف سند حسابداری</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
        <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I want.

I want the child not to be wider than its parent and if it is, then it must scroll. But when I use a fieldset, every thing mixes up. Take a look at this:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<fieldset style="width:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li><a>test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
        <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the JS Fiddle here:

[correct](https://jsfiddle.net/pob2jjpm/)

[wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/xLf1Lxuz/)

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you using fieldset here?

Comment: It is just a test for stackoverflow. just a demo. but in my project i should use. there isn't any other way!

Comment: Do you use any kind of normalize.css? Fieldsets by default do have alot of browser styling to them so this could be the source of your breakage. Can you add a broken JSFiddle?

Comment: Provide your actual code and also your css

Comment: @DCdaz there is n't any need to the real code. it is asp web form and i should use fieldset. the css is't needed. the code i gave you is enough.

Comment: actually there is your css is pretty vital considering you dont appear to have a reset in place or any css at all to do with fieldset and you are asking what the issue is.

Comment: @DCdaz i mean this code is enough. see the jsfiddle and reach that this is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. The answers of the friends who answered here was helpful to me and the answer was very far from my mind! This is the corrected html:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<fieldset style="width:97%; min-width:0;">
    <ul>
        <li><a>test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
        <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

You see? the min-width is the problem! I don't know how it mixes every thing up but it does! The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660423/fieldset-width-100-of-parent) helped me (my question will be a duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

Fieldset's are one of many tag's that come with browser defined styles this is why we use reset's.

I have my own reset but you can pick one's up online like [html5docs](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) (put this at the top of your CSS file.)

The reason you need a reset is because if you look at the source code for `fieldset` in say Chrome you will see that Chrome automatically applies these rules to `fieldset`.

```css
fieldset {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-start: 2px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 2px;
    -webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
    -webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
    -webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
    border: 2px groove threedface;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    min-width: -webkit-min-content;
}
```

The reason browser's automatically apply style rules to certain elements is because these element's are meant to be used in specific way's and the browser applies there common usage styling so that when placed in a document they are recognizable for what they are.

In your case a `fieldset` which shows a group of fields that can be edited by the user.

**update**

Your Question was really unclear so.

`Fieldset` is a block level element you are wanting it to act like and inline element so give it `display:inline;`

Comment: so. what is the property i should reset? what causes the problem?

Comment: so let me pull you out of shock. i copied that code and used to style my fieldset element but nothing changed! i mean that which property of fieldset i should change to reach the result?

Comment: js fiddle me what you have done

Comment: because it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/xLf1Lxuz/1/

Comment: I saw the jsfiddle you gave but it was not correct!!! i tested just as you did in jsfiddle.

Comment: What are you talking about. You need that reset on your site. there is no two ways about it. otherwise you are going to keep hitting walls like this. the reset doesnt just effect Fields. this answer has been voted up 5 times think about it it's not wrong. actually look at the css notice how the very first set of rules effect fieldset  and many other styles.

Comment: I am talking about the problem that is not fixed yet. you gave me jsfiddle and i saw it but take a look and you will see that still "the width of fieldset does not match it's parent". am i wrong? my question from the start was how make the fieldset as wide as its parent and i am seeking for the answer of that and nothing else. your answer about reseting css styles was awsome but not the answer i wanted and still ... .

Comment: you have three elements at 100%..... So it is actually the same width. do you mean that you want this to happen https://jsfiddle.net/xLf1Lxuz/3/

Comment: "inspect element" it and you will see that the width of fieldset is not equal to its parent and it is much bigger.

Comment: then why do you want a scroll? check my answer again

Comment: see the answer i've added and you'll got it. thanks.

Comment: Fieldset is a block level element you are wanting it to act like and inline element so give it display:inline; like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
<fieldset style="width:100%">
<ul>
<li><a>test</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="width:100%">
 <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

you can try to put overflow-x:scroll; on your div

Comment: I have tested this too before. but the thing is, the code you gave solves the whole page scrolling but the fieldset width is still stretched! Agree?

Comment: ok or you can decrease the width of your div like <div style="width:70%; overflow-x:scroll;">

Comment: it doesn't work. thanks.