# Fitting a <fieldset> to the size of its content with CSS?

Tags: html, css, fieldset

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDMfN/3/).

I need to make the `<fieldset>` the width of its contents, rather than its parent. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to have a fieldset width only be as wide as the controls in them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302495/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-fieldset-width-only-be-as-wide-as-the-controls-in-the)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a shrinkwrap?

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meder/XDMfN/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <form>
      <fieldset>
         <legend>Hey</legend>
         <table>
            <thead><tr><td>H1</td><td>H2</td></tr></thead>
            <tbody><tr><td>A1</td><td>B2</td></tr>
               <tr><td>A2</td><td>B9</td></tr></tbody>
         </table>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset{
   border: solid 2px blue;  
   float:left;
}
table{
   border: solid 2px red;   
}
div{
   width: 80%;   
   overflow:hidden;
   border: solid 2px purple;
   padding: 1em;
}
```

**Output**

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: This answer doesn't actually have an answer in it.

Answer (score 23):

Add display:inline to the fieldset
http://jsfiddle.net/XDMfN/92/

Comment: That link doesn't demonstrate display:inline, as you are using the same link as meder above.  +1 However, using display:inline did work for me, and I prefer that over using floats.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the link to show how to add display:inline, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your CSS

```
fieldset 
{
     display: inline;
}
```