# How to make fieldset to expand and compress dynamically

Tags: html, css, css-float, datatables, stylesheet

i have a [datatable](https://www.datatables.net/) displayed in fieldset, here is my fieldset attributes in css

```
#ResultFieldset
{
    position: absolute;
    width:4500px;
    top:72px;
    left:270px;
}
```

Whenever the data in table is hidden or removed, the fieldset should collapse, but its not happening. table shrinks and expands but fieldset remain constant, how to make it dynamic?

HTML

```
<fieldset id="ResultFieldset">
     <legend>results</legend>

            <h2>Results</h2>

    <div id = "GridDiv"  style="display: none;">    
    <div id='Holder'>
    </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: Do you put your DB results into Holder div?

Comment: Yes flipko, it comes in holder.. but its under ResultFieldset

Comment: Do you render your data using JavaScript or some scripting language?

Comment: java script only... i use jquery to get data

Comment: This may need a fiddle in order for us to see what's happening more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759260/how-do-i-fit-a-fieldset-to-the-size-of-its-content-with-css) question. When you change your content data dynamicly, you will need to use JavaScript or another client side script.

Comment: oh.. any alterntive way apart from this?. is it not possible to do anything in css?

Comment: Try to set `display: inline-block` to your fieldset.