# make fieldset right side "stick" to the table outline instead of parent div

Tags: html

I have a Div, Fieldset and Table.  the table takes about 40% of the width of the screen and I want the fieldset to outline it.  It works on all sides except for the right side and extends all the way to the right side of the screen.  Is there a way to make it stick to the table?

Comment: Please post what you have so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there anyway to have a fieldset width only be as wide as the controls in them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302495/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-fieldset-width-only-be-as-wide-as-the-controls-in-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `<fieldset>` to `display:inline-block;`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SkYyP/).

```
fieldset { display: inline-block; }
```

*See also [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302495/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-fieldset-width-only-be-as-wide-as-the-controls-in-them)*