# How to fix fieldset width

Tags: css, fieldset

I have a fieldset with an `<a>` tag as child. When I resize the child the fieldset's width changes as well even if I set a width property. However, the height doesn't change. I would like to know how to set a fixed width.

```css
fieldset {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 80px;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 5px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 4px 15px 0px;
}


a {
      background-color: red;
      border-color: rgb(212, 214, 216);
      border-width: 20px;
      box-shadow: rgb(212, 214, 216) 0.5px 0.5px 1px 0px;
      width: 50px;
}

.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background: white;
    color: #303030;
    border: 10px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px 0px #d4d6d8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Preview</legend>
    <a class="Preview"></a> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please provide us full snippet including HTML

Comment: Are you changing the width of `a`? If so then nothing is happening (at least to me) since it's an inline element which doesn't have such properties as width and height.

Comment: I made a fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/frya5j2x/7/

Comment: Please include all relevant code from your fiddle in the question itself. Please don't make people go to another site just to answer your question. Also, your question is not terribly clear. You're already setting a fixed width in your CSS.

Comment: `a` is an inline element which does not accept `width`.

Comment: Width on a element is working fine. The point is I want to fix the width of the fieldset element. If I change the width on the a element or the padding or whatever that can affect the width, the fieldset width changes.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, I just want to have a fixed fieldset width. Nothing more, nothing less. Can you just open the fiddle and change the width of the a element and you'll see.

Comment: If I change the width or the border-width of <a> for instance. The fieldset doesn't keeps his width.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302495/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-fieldset-width-only-be-as-wide-as-the-controls-in-the#2302539

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't seems to work.
Here, the height is working as he should, but not the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Basically, I put the `<a>` into a `<div>` and I give the `<div>` a height and a width which is the same as the fieldset, then the size of the fieldset doesn't increase if I change the size of whatever is into the `<div>`